# How to remove multiple joins, It's take more time to execute.How to improve query result

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter-3

I execute the following query in MySQL database, Query working fine But its take more time to execute.
I am trying to optimize the query but didn't find any solution to optimize the query.
Please help me to optimize the query.

```
SELECT count( distinct login_history.user_id) as total_count
FROM `login_history
JOIN (SELECT *
FROM `login_details` UNION SELECT *
FROM `deleted_login_details`) as login_details ON `login_details`.`l_id` = `login_history`.`user_id`
LEFT JOIN `group_learners` ON `group_learners`.`user_id`=`login_details`.`l_id` AND `group_learners`.`status` = "0"
LEFT JOIN `learner_custom_field_details` as `l14` ON `l14`.`learner_id` = `login_history`.`user_id`
LEFT JOIN `learner_custom_field_details` as `l16` ON `l16`.`learner_id` = `login_history`.`user_id`
LEFT JOIN `learner_custom_field_details` as `l17` ON `l17`.`learner_id` = `login_history`.`user_id`
LEFT JOIN `learner_custom_field_details` as `l18` ON `l18`.`learner_id` = `login_history`.`user_id`
LEFT JOIN `learner_custom_field_details` as `l19` ON `l19`.`learner_id` = `login_history`.`user_id`
LEFT JOIN `learner_custom_field_details` as `l20` ON `l20`.`learner_id` = `login_history`.`user_id`
LEFT JOIN `learner_custom_field_details` as `l21` ON `l21`.`learner_id` = `login_history`.`user_id`
LEFT JOIN `learner_custom_field_details` ON `learner_custom_field_details`.`learner_id` = `login_history`.`user_id`
WHERE `login_details`.`user_type` NOT IN('1', '2', '4')
AND ( 1=1
AND `l14`.`custom_field_id` = 14
AND `l14`.`custom_value` IN('1', '2')
AND  1=1)
AND ( 1=1
AND `l16`.`custom_field_id` = 16
AND `l16`.`custom_value` IN('3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '283')
AND  1=1)
AND ( 1=1
AND `l17`.`custom_field_id` = 17
AND `l17`.`custom_value` IN('25', '26', '27', '28', '29', '30', '31', '32', '33', '34', '35', '36', '37', '38', '39', '40', '41', '42', '43', '44', '45', '46', '47', '48', '49', '50', '51')
AND  1=1)
AND ( 1=1
AND `l18`.`custom_field_id` = 18
AND `l18`.`custom_value` IN('52', '53', '54', '55', '56', '57', '58', '59', '60', '61', '62', '63', '64', '65', '66', '67', '68', '69', '70', '71', '72', '73', '74', '75', '76', '77', '78')
AND  1=1)
AND ( 1=1
AND `l19`.`custom_field_id` = 19
AND `l19`.`custom_value` IN('79', '80', '81', '82', '83', '84', '85', '86', '87', '88', '89', '90', '91', '92', '93', '94', '95', '96')
AND  1=1)
AND ( 1=1
AND `l20`.`custom_field_id` = 20
AND `l20`.`custom_value` IN('97', '98', '99', '100', '101', '102', '103', '104', '105', '106', '107', '108', '109', '110', '111', '112', '113', '114', '115', '116', '117', '118', '119', '120', '121', '122', '123', '124', '125', '126', '127', '128', '129', '130', '131', '132', '133', '134', '135', '136', '137', '138', '139', '140', '142', '143', '144', '145', '146', '147', '148', '149', '150', '151', '152', '153', '154', '155', '156', '157', '158', '159', '160', '161', '162', '163', '164', '165', '166', '167', '168', '169', '170', '171', '172', '173', '174', '175', '176', '177', '178', '179', '180', '181', '182', '183', '184', '280')
AND  1=1)
AND ( 1=1
AND `l21`.`custom_field_id` = 21
AND `l21`.`custom_value` IN('185', '186', '187', '188', '189', '190', '191', '192', '193', '194', '195', '196', '197', '198', '199', '200', '201', '202', '203', '204', '205', '206', '207', '208', '209', '210', '211', '212', '213', '214', '215', '216', '217', '218', '219', '220', '221', '222', '223', '224', '225', '226', '227', '228', '229', '230', '231', '232', '233', '234', '235', '236', '237', '238', '239', '240', '241', '242', '243', '244', '245', '246', '247', '248', '249', '250', '251', '252', '253', '254', '255', '256', '257', '258', '259', '260', '261', '262', '263', '264', '265', '266', '267', '268', '269', '270', '272', '273', '274', '281', '282')
AND  1=1)
AND `login_details`.`l_branch` IN('1')
```

Comment: Do an explain plan and make sure that you have the right indexes.

Comment: I have already apply indexes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of the ways, But I am sure you can make a view from the last join part, which have different l18,l19, l20, ...  then make your join simple...

```html
with cteUnion as (
SELECT *
 FROM `login_details` 
  WHERE `login_details`.`user_type` NOT IN('1', '2', '4') AND `login_details`.`l_branch` IN('1')
  UNION 
SELECT *
FROM 
`deleted_login_details`
),
group_learnersStatus as (
select * 
from `group_learners`
where `status` = "0"

),

SELECT count( distinct login_history.user_id), login_history.user_id as total_count
FROM `login_history
JOIN cteUnion as login_details ON `login_details`.`l_id` = `login_history`.`user_id`
LEFT JOIN group_learnersStatus ON `group_learners`.`user_id`=`login_details`.`l_id` 
LEFT JOIN `learner_custom_field_details` as `l14` ON `l14`.`learner_id` = `login_history`.`user_id` AND `l14`.`custom_field_id` = 14
AND `l14`.`custom_value` IN('1', '2')
LEFT JOIN `learner_custom_field_details` as `l16` ON `l16`.`learner_id` = `login_history`.`user_id` AND `l16`.`custom_field_id` = 16
AND `l16`.`custom_value` IN('3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '283')
LEFT JOIN `learner_custom_field_details` as `l17` ON `l17`.`learner_id` = `login_history`.`user_id` AND `l17`.`custom_field_id` = 17
AND `l17`.`custom_value` IN('25', '26', '27', '28', '29', '30', '31', '32', '33', '34', '35', '36', '37', '38', '39', '40', '41', '42', '43', '44', '45', '46', '47', '48', '49', '50', '51')
LEFT JOIN `learner_custom_field_details` as `l18` ON `l18`.`learner_id` = `login_history`.`user_id`  AND `l18`.`custom_field_id` = 18
AND `l18`.`custom_value` IN('52', '53', '54', '55', '56', '57', '58', '59', '60', '61', '62', '63', '64', '65', '66', '67', '68', '69', '70', '71', '72', '73', '74', '75', '76', '77', '78')
LEFT JOIN `learner_custom_field_details` as `l19` ON `l19`.`learner_id` = `login_history`.`user_id` AND `l19`.`custom_field_id` = 19
AND `l19`.`custom_value` IN('79', '80', '81', '82', '83', '84', '85', '86', '87', '88', '89', '90', '91', '92', '93', '94', '95', '96')
LEFT JOIN `learner_custom_field_details` as `l20` ON `l20`.`learner_id` = `login_history`.`user_id` AND `l20`.`custom_value` IN('97', '98', '99', '100', '101', '102', '103', '104', '105', '106', '107', '108', '109', '110', '111', '112', '113', '114', '115', '116', '117', '118', '119', '120', '121', '122', '123', '124', '125', '126', '127', '128', '129', '130', '131', '132', '133', '134', '135', '136', '137', '138', '139', '140', '142', '143', '144', '145', '146', '147', '148', '149', '150', '151', '152', '153', '154', '155', '156', '157', '158', '159', '160', '161', '162', '163', '164', '165', '166', '167', '168', '169', '170', '171', '172', '173', '174', '175', '176', '177', '178', '179', '180', '181', '182', '183', '184', '280')
LEFT JOIN `learner_custom_field_details` as `l21` ON `l21`.`learner_id` = `login_history`.`user_id` AND `l21`.`custom_field_id` = 21
AND `l21`.`custom_value` IN('185', '186', '187', '188', '189', '190', '191', '192', '193', '194', '195', '196', '197', '198', '199', '200', '201', '202', '203', '204', '205', '206', '207', '208', '209', '210', '211', '212', '213', '214', '215', '216', '217', '218', '219', '220', '221', '222', '223', '224', '225', '226', '227', '228', '229', '230', '231', '232', '233', '234', '235', '236', '237', '238', '239', '240', '241', '242', '243', '244', '245', '246', '247', '248', '249', '250', '251', '252', '253', '254', '255', '256', '257', '258', '259', '260', '261', '262', '263', '264', '265', '266', '267', '268', '269', '270', '272', '273', '274', '281', '282')
LEFT JOIN `learner_custom_field_details` ON `learner_custom_field_details`.`learner_id` = `login_history`.`user_id`
```

Answer (score 1):

I would be tempted to try the following

```
SELECT
    COUNT( user_id ) AS total_count
FROM (
    SELECT
        login_history.user_id
    FROM login_history
    INNER JOIN group_learners ON group_learners.user_id = login_history.user_id
        AND group_learners.status = "0"
    UNION
    SELECT
        login_history.user_id
    FROM login_history
    INNER JOIN learner_custom_field_details AS l14 ON login_history.user_id = login_history.user_id
        AND l14.custom_field_id = 14
        AND l14.custom_value IN ('1', '2')
    UNION
    SELECT
        login_history.user_id
    FROM login_history
    INNER JOIN learner_custom_field_details AS l16 ON l16.learner_id = login_history.user_id
        AND l16.custom_field_id = 16
        AND l16.custom_value IN ('3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '283')
    UNION
    SELECT
        login_history.user_id
    FROM login_history
    INNER JOIN learner_custom_field_details AS l17 ON l17.learner_id = login_history.user_id
        AND l17.custom_field_id = 17
        AND l17.custom_value IN ('25', '26', '27', '28', '29', '30', '31', '32', '33', '34', '35', '36', '37', '38', '39', '40', '41', '42', '43', '44', '45', '46', '47', '48', '49', '50', '51')
    UNION
    SELECT
        login_history.user_id
    FROM login_history
    INNER JOIN learner_custom_field_details AS l18 ON l18.learner_id = login_history.user_id
        AND l18.custom_field_id = 18
        AND l18.custom_value IN ('52', '53', '54', '55', '56', '57', '58', '59', '60', '61', '62', '63', '64', '65', '66', '67', '68', '69', '70', '71', '72', '73', '74', '75', '76', '77', '78')
    UNION
    SELECT
        login_history.user_id
    FROM login_history
    INNER JOIN learner_custom_field_details AS l19 ON l19.learner_id = login_history.user_id
        AND l19.custom_field_id = 19
        AND l19.custom_value IN ('79', '80', '81', '82', '83', '84', '85', '86', '87', '88', '89', '90', '91', '92', '93', '94', '95', '96')
    UNION
    SELECT
        login_history.user_id
    FROM login_history
    INNER JOIN learner_custom_field_details AS l20 ON l20.learner_id = login_history.user_id
        AND l20.custom_field_id = 20
        AND l20.custom_value IN ('97', '98', '99', '100', '101', '102', '103', '104', '105', '106', '107', '108', '109', '110', '111', '112', '113', '114', '115', '116', '117', '118', '119', '120', '121', '122', '123', '124', '125', '126', '127', '128', '129', '130', '131', '132', '133', '134', '135', '136', '137', '138', '139', '140', '142', '143', '144', '145', '146', '147', '148', '149', '150', '151', '152', '153', '154', '155', '156', '157', '158', '159', '160', '161', '162', '163', '164', '165', '166', '167', '168', '169', '170', '171', '172', '173', '174', '175', '176', '177', '178', '179', '180', '181', '182', '183', '184', '280')
    UNION
    SELECT
        login_history.user_id
    FROM login_history
    INNER JOIN learner_custom_field_details AS l21 ON l21.learner_id = login_history.user_id
        AND l21.custom_field_id = 21
        AND l21.custom_value IN ('185', '186', '187', '188', '189', '190', '191', '192', '193', '194', '195', '196', '197', '198', '199', '200', '201', '202', '203', '204', '205', '206', '207', '208', '209', '210', '211', '212', '213', '214', '215', '216', '217', '218', '219', '220', '221', '222', '223', '224', '225', '226', '227', '228', '229', '230', '231', '232', '233', '234', '235', '236', '237', '238', '239', '240', '241', '242', '243', '244', '245', '246', '247', '248', '249', '250', '251', '252', '253', '254', '255', '256', '257', '258', '259', '260', '261', '262', '263', '264', '265', '266', '267', '268', '269', '270', '272', '273', '274', '281', '282')
    UNION
    SELECT
        login_history.user_id
    FROM login_history
    INNER JOIN learner_custom_field_details ON learner_custom_field_details.learner_id = login_history.user_id
) u
WHERE (
EXISTS (
    SELECT
        NULL
    FROM login_details
    WHERE user_type NOT IN ('1', '2', '4')
    AND l_branch IN ('1')
    AND user_id = u.user_id
    )
OR EXISTS (
    SELECT
        NULL
    FROM deleted_login_details
    WHERE user_type NOT IN ('1', '2', '4')
    AND l_branch IN ('1')
    AND user_id = u.user_id
    )
)
```